# Requested registry allow access without security leaks

Tags: c#, registry

Right now i am using an web application with code to read from and write to the registry. While debugging in Visual studio everything went fine but on the online test server it didn't run. the error exception message i am getting is:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not
>   allowed.

This is the code i am using:

```
  private RegistryKey GetWritableBaseRegistryKey(string extendedPath)
        {
            var path = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall";
            return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Default).OpenSubKey($"{path}\\{extendedPath}", true);
        }
```

The sollutions i found where:

Solution 1

> you will not be able to set AppPoolIdentity to a specific group, but
>   you can
>
> 1. create a local user (compmgmt.msc)
> 2. add the user to the administrator group (compmgmt.msc)
> 3. Set the application pool to run under that user, under Advanced Settings.
>
> Obviously you know this is a very bad idea from a security
>   perspective, and should never ever ever be performed on a forward
>   facing server.
>   [source](https://superuser.com/questions/775556/iis-apppool-administrator?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Solution 2

> Create a separate console application to run the service in admin
>   modus so you could access the registry. This solution was performance
>   heavy because you need to run 2 separate applications.

Solution 3

> Use this code to allow access to the registry.
>
> ```
> RegistryPermission perm1 = new RegistryPermission(RegistryPermissionAccess.AllAccess, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall");
>                         perm1.Demand();
> ```
>
> Or this code
>
> ```
> RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
>                     string currentUserStr = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
>                     RegistryAccessRule accessRule = new RegistryAccessRule(currentUserStr, RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete | RegistryRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
>                     rs.AddAccessRule(accessRule);
> ```
>
> But these didn't work on the server however while debugging in visual studio the code ran fine.

Comment: You just don't.... Why would you even need access to registry in web app? (Feels [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) )

Answer (score 1):

In order for the web application to access the registry it must have sufficient permission. Consequently Solution 1 is the only one likely to work. It describes setting the web sites application pool to a user in the local administrators group. Its misses the steps about actually setting your IIS web site to use the newly created App Pool, which is why it might not work for you.

The technical process of reading a restricted registry, especially the application Uninstall registry key, inside a web server is really unlikely to be useful to you. Of what possible use is allowing a web server to access the servers own Application uninstall list going to be ?

I suspect you intend to open that registry key on the client's PC (my speculation) which is not going to be possible.

Comment: Side note: I think error they are getting is from .Net CAS and not Windows level security check yet, so they may need 1+3 (Windows permissions and .Net `Demand`) for hosted web app...